# Keep only one .panel-body opened

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have four accordions using Bootstrap's [Collapse](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) plugin. It works nicely, but I would like to have only one `.panel-body` at once. This works in one `.panel-group`, but I need this to work in all four. So, how can I detect if there's one active and close the rest in other accordions?

Here's an example of what I have now http://jsfiddle.net/9gELd/2/

Comment: Can you post your code? Normally that's how the Bootstrap accordion panels work... Only 1 open at a time: http://bootply.com/98769

Comment: @Skelly Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/9gELd/2/ — But I want to open one among all the accordions (4 of them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using javascript, try this:

```
$(function() {
  $('.panel-collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('.panel-collapse').not( document.getElementById($( this ).attr('id') ))
    .removeClass('in')
    .addClass('collapse');
   })
});
```